# Only keypress is recognized, no key release

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, keyboard

I've been trying for quite some time to map my audio controls to the corresponding XF86 keys. However,three keys: `XF86AudioLowerVolume`, `XF86AudioRaiseVolume` & `XF86AudioMute` refuse to work properly.
After each login, I can press each of these keys exactly once. Afterwards, their input is repeated until I press another key or send another key signal. `xev` also shows a repeating keypress from these keys, and `showkey` shows only a keypress event, but no release. To clarify, this is what the output looks like:

```
keycode 113 press
keycode 114 press
keycode 115 press
 keycode  57 press
keycode  57 release
```

You can see that the spacebar (keycode 57) shows a release as expected, but keycodes 113-115 don't.
Now I have looked all around on the internet, but I haven't seen another post in which only the key press is registered, and not the key release. I recently upgraded to ubuntu 19.10 and reinstalled `xorg` but to no avail. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT:

For all of the three keys, I only get an output in `xev` the first time I press it; the key is just repeated over and over again, like this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x168, subw 0x0, time 35686, (441,184), root:(1725,204),
    state 0x0, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x168, subw 0x0, time 36347, (441,184), root:(1725,204),
    state 0x0, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
        ........
```

What surprises me is the line `XLookupString gives 0 bytes:`, that can't be right? Normal keys a single byte here, which corresponds to the output character. Other XF86 keys give me events like this:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 157, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14  
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Also, the keycodes that show up in xev to correspond to the correct bindings when I run `xmodmap -pke`. I am inclined to believe that the problem isn't with my X server, because restarting the X server with [`sudo systemctl restart display-manager`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222) does nothing for me, neither does relogging.

I've also tried restarting the keyboard with

```
xinput disable 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'; 
xinput enable 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
```

but to no avail.

I've tried restarting the atkbd module (the keyboard controller) with commands such as `modprobe -r atkbd` only to receive messages like `modprobe: FATAL: Module atkbd is builtin`.

So far, the only way to press (and never release) those keys is to restart.

Perhaps it is important to tell that I run a dual booted system with `GRUB2`. In Windows, the keys work just fine. I guess they also do in the bios, although that's a little hard to test for volume keys.

---

EDIT 2:

I am using a Medion Erazer P6661 laptop with built-in keyboard.
By listing my keyboard with [`xinput list-props 12`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282296/279016), I get the following information:

```
Device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard':
    Device Enabled (167):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (169): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (289): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (290):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (291):    0, 0
    Device Node (292):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (293):    1, 1
```

Comment: I'm using a Medion Erazer P6661 laptop with built-in keyboard, and yes I do use the Fn-keys to access these.
I just found out that there are more keys which don't function properly, such as the `XF86Sleep` key, although I don't ever use that one. Almost all of them - brightness up- and down, etc., function properly.

Comment: Probably the only thing that comes to my mind that I would do if that was my laptop is updating BIOS (UEFI) .. [see download page](https://www.medion.com/gb/service/download/driver.php) But it appears they provide the BIOS package only for Windows10.

Comment: I ended up just updating my BIOS via windows to version 2.22, which didn't fix the problem. However, now my touchpad also doesn't work anymore!
Perhaps related is that when running `xinput`, the touchpad now has id 12 (earlier beloning to the keyboard) and the keyboard is shifted up to id 13.

Comment: I resolved the touchpad issue following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1091635/1017771). Still haven't gotten the function keys working, though.

Comment: I'm glad the touchpad is *only* a kernel bug and has a workaround!