# Touchpad no longer recognized after updating BIOS and kernel

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, input

[While trying to fix some of my function keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/550363/279016), I decided to update my BIOS. Although this didn't solve my original issue, my touchpad was no longer working!

Initially, after the first reboot, it still showed up in `/proc/bus/input/devices` and `xinput`, but just didn't seem to work. Then, Ubuntu (19.10) prompted me to install a lot of new updates.

First of all, I couldn't boot into ubuntu anymore from GRUB2 (I run dual-boot with windows), although that was quickly resolved by changing my kernel to `vmlinuz-5.3.0-19-generic` in the entry (from 4.xx-23 I believe).

Then, after finally successfully rebooting, my touchpad doesn't show up in `/proc/bus/input/devices` or `xinput` at all anymore! The only trace I managed to find was this output in `dmesg`:

```
[    2.471492] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x461f01)
[    2.474830] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:4: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
[    2.487000] psmouse serio4: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x00, 0x16, 0x0d.
[    2.504567] psmouse serio4: elantech: Elan sample query result 01, 7b, 75
[    2.534034] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    2.534644] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    2.534709] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    2.534797] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    2.534806] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    2.535269] psmouse serio4: elantech: Trying to set up SMBus access
[    2.557682] EXT4-fs (sdb5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    2.560654] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    2.569821] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    2.712339] Adding 2097148k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:5 across:2260988k SSFS
[    2.748547] elan_i2c 0-0015: 0-0015 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.756831] elan_i2c 0-0015: failed to get product ID: -71
[    2.803035] elan_i2c 0-0015: failed to get product ID: -71
[    2.847035] elan_i2c 0-0015: failed to get product ID: -71
[    2.883114] elan_i2c: probe of 0-0015 failed with error -71
```

Does anybody have a clue on how to fix this?

---

EDIT:

After [LinuxSecurityFreak's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553127/touchpad-no-longer-recognized-after-updating-bios-and-kernel#comment1027032_553127) I tried activating the touchpad with:

```
sudo rmmod elan_i2c
sudo modprobe elan_i2c
```

After which the touchpad does show up again in `/proc/bus/input/devices` and `xinput`! But.. It still doesn't work.

`/var/log/syslog` reports the following for `sudo rmmod elan_i2c`:

```
Nov 20 14:19:25 User xdg-desktop-por[1895]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Nov 20 14:20:03 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) config/udev: removing device Elan Touchpad
Nov 20 14:20:03 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Option "fd" "56"
Nov 20 14:20:03 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) event16 - Elan Touchpad: device removed
Nov 20 14:20:03 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Nov 20 14:20:03 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:80
Nov 20 14:20:03 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (EE) systemd-logind: failed to release device: Device not taken
```

and for `sudo modprobe elan_i2c`:

```
Nov 20 14:20:06 User kernel: [  359.718149] elan_i2c 0-0015: 0-0015 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
Nov 20 14:20:06 User kernel: [  359.726146] elan_i2c 0-0015: failed to get product ID: -71
Nov 20 14:20:06 User kernel: [  359.775575] elan_i2c 0-0015: Elan Touchpad: Module ID: 0x0000, Firmware: 0x0000, Sample: 0x0000, IAP: 0x0000
Nov 20 14:20:06 User kernel: [  359.776325] input: Elan Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.4/i2c-0/0-0015/input/input26
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Elan Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1195]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Elan Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1195]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1195]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Elan Touchpad (/dev/input/event16)
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Elan Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Elan Touchpad'
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1195]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Elan Touchpad (/dev/input/event16)
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1195]: (**) Elan Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1195]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Elan Touchpad'
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event16 13:80 fd 66 paused 0
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Elan Touchpad: always reports core events
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event16"
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) event16 - Elan Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1195]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event16 13:80 fd 30 paused 1
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1195]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:80
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) event16 - Elan Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) event16 - Elan Touchpad: device removed
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.4/i2c-0/0-0015/input/input26/event16"
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Elan Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 14)
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Elan Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Elan Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (**) Elan Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) event16 - Elan Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
Nov 20 14:20:06 User /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) event16 - Elan Touchpad: device is a touchpad
```

Strangely enough, running the same commands again the touchpad disappears yet again, with `sudo modprobe elan_i2c` giving a different output:

```
ov 20 14:22:19 User kernel: [  492.932593] elan_i2c 0-0015: 0-0015 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
Nov 20 14:22:19 User kernel: [  492.940679] elan_i2c 0-0015: failed to get product ID: -71
Nov 20 14:22:19 User kernel: [  492.986685] elan_i2c 0-0015: failed to get product ID: -71
Nov 20 14:22:19 User kernel: [  493.034988] elan_i2c 0-0015: failed to get product ID: -71
Nov 20 14:22:19 User kernel: [  493.074890] elan_i2c: probe of 0-0015 failed with error -71
```

Comment: Can't fall asleep,... it *might* be related to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1683508) Please have a look, I did not study it too deep.

Answer (score 2):

[This question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1091635) seems to have been about the exact same bug, and the corresponding answer fixed my problem. In short:

- Run `sudo sh -c 'echo -n "elantech"> /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol'` to get the touchpad working after boot, or
- Add `psmouse.elantech_smbus=0` to your boot options to fix at startup.